# Crankset with one chainring and two chain guards?

Tags: crankset, chainring, electric-bike

I would like to custom build a crankset which would like the one I have on my ebike, but with more teeth. My current chainring is 52T, and I would like to go up to 58T. What I have is a four bolt, crankset, with two chain guards. Unfortunately, I am told that it is one piece, forged together somehow, and cannot be taken apart. So, I need to make one myself from parts found in ebay and aliexpress. What I was thinking was buying a 58T chainring, two chainguards, and a 130BCD crankset. Does this make sense? Would it all fit?  Are chainrings all metal? Should I worry about plastik? Would it be about the thickness?

Why would I want one? My ebike reaches 30KMH, at which speed I am spinning out... I have 6 gear shimano, but with the motor, I never use anything but the highest gear. I would like at times go faster, pedal assisting the motor, so as to gain few KMH.

The objective is a relatively cheap speed + exercise combination.

I figured out the math that in adding 11.5% (58/52 - 1) to the number of teeth, I could be spinning out at 33 km/h. This is not very much, but it may be cost-effective vs the alternative of changing the motor and controller.

My rear wheel is 20", so the relatively large and not so common chainring does make sense.

[image]

Comment: 1. Will a chainguard be as big as a 58t chainring? 
2. Why do you need 2 chainguards? 
3. A 58t chainring might interfere with the chainstay. 
4. Apart from some very exotic carbon-fiber ones, chainrings are aluminum (or perhaps steel for very cheap ones).
5. It looks like you've got an integrated chainring/spider. Hard to say. It might be replaceable, but you'd need to know how it mates to the spindle to find a replacement.

Comment: I found a crankset on ebay, https://www.ebay.com/itm/273922968650?hash=item3fc714cc4a:g:oPEAAOSwhJFdJaum with 58T. My current has two guards, which seems to be the standard. I edited the question to explain why I would want one.

Comment: "Spinning out" at 30km/h on a 54 chain ring. What's the wheel size and rear cluster sizes.   A 58 won't make that much difference.

Comment: "ebay and aliexpress" your LBS will also be able to get parts that will work and will be far less likely to maim you

Comment: Replacing your cassette might also be a much easier and cheaper option to consider

Comment: What is your current cassette?   If its a freewheel then the lowest toothcount (hardest gear) is probably a 14 tooth.  If its a cassette, then you can get down to 11 tooth smallest cog.   At those counts, 12 to 11 is about a 9% improvement.

Comment: I notice your bike has those flexible folding pedals - if you're putting power down through those, they will bend and eventually fail.  Consider some normal pedals if you don't require them to fold up.

Comment: @mattnz: This is a 20" wheel. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

The "two chainguards" is a cheap way of keeping your chain on and keeping clothes off the chain.  You could use a narrow-wide chainring to assist in chain retention, and tuck your trouser cuff into your sock.